# Export to pdf button click event automatically calls 3 times+itext dll+asp.net,c#

Tags: asp.net

I am usinng iText dll to export html to pdf.
an asp button is used for exporting.pdf is generating but  the button click event is automatically calling 3 times.
here is the code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf");

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    gvDetails.RenderControl(hw);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

    iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f,0.0f);

    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

    pdfDoc.Open();

    htmlparser.Parse(sr);

    pdfDoc.Close();

    Response.Write(pdfDoc);

    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: can you post the html for your page, there must be something which is calling this submit button three times

Answer (score 0):

I would check the code that wires up the event handler.
It may seem like it's wired up multiple times, which results in the method being invoked multiple times